# Puppeteer - click not executed sometimes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, puppeteer

I have an issue with the click behavior which I cannot figure out.

### Setup

- Typescript: 2.9.0-insiders-20180510
- Jest: 22.4.3
- Puppeteer version: 1.4.0
- Platform / OS version: Win10
- Node.js version: 8.9.0

### Code

```
await page.waitFor(gameActionButtonSelector(2, "Deactivate"));
console.log(await page.content());
await page.click(gameActionButtonSelector(2, "Deactivate"));
await page.waitFor(gameActionButtonSelector(2, "Activate"));
```

### Problem

Sometimes the click is not executed, although the element is there. In the above code I logged the page html and I can see the element there, but it is still not clicked. No exception is thrown on the click action.

Let me know if more details are needed

Comment: I guess it's near impossible to reproduce without an actual page. What does `gameActionButtonSelector` look like?

Comment: It just creates a selector, as it is dynamic, based on the properties. I found the issue however. Looks like the previous test was showing a popover that was hiding the center of the button I am trying to click.. so lame.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

Looks like the previous test was showing a popover that was hiding the center of the button I am trying to click.. so lame.

Comment: Nothing helpful, close the issue?)